Terminal not displaying installation progress properly
I recently bought a new laptop,
normally while downloading node modules from terminal proper installation progress as well as text come up but in my new laptop, only a spinner comes up.
[In New Laptop]
[In Old Laptop]
Is this issue genuine (related to difference in node version)?
Does someone have ans to this problem (really irritating)?
I have tried every thing suggested by chat gpt or gemini. Still unable to fix this issue.

You inserted a \ character at the end of the command. The command never started

Not actually, this is the spinner i was taking about

You can spin to false to fix it.
So this will be the command:
npm config set spin=false

Also some people think when it doesn't spin that it is frozen or something is wrong but it is just downloading a lot of packages.
You can read more about this issue here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5340

I already have the latest version of npm. So, there is no option to set spin
''' npm error spin is not a valid npm option '''

@AryanGarg Idk, can you try and wait maybe it is downloading packages, also you can use other package managers like yarn and bun instead of npm if it has a problem. You can also create an issue on the github repo, so you can get direct support from them
